# How to add row in MVVM pattern?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, mvvm, telerik

Say I use xaml to create a telerik RadGridView.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="myRadGridView" 
                             Width="1000" 
                             IsReadOnly="True" 
                             ValidatesOnDataErrors="None" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                             IsFilteringAllowed="False" 
                             ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                             ShowColumnFooters="False" 
                             CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                             CanUserFreezeColumns="False" 
                             SelectionMode="Single" 
                             CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                             CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                             CanUserInsertRows="False" 
                             CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                             CanUserSelect="True" 
                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Visible" 
                             Height="250" 
                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Information}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             SelectionChanged="myRadGridView_SelectionChanged"
            >
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewColumn />
            <telerik:GridViewColumn />
            .....
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

There are many columns.
I get the data from my ViewModel. Now I want to add a new row to get the total value of the above rows.

My question is that how to add the row in my ViewModel?

Comment: Have you checked the Telerik.Windows.Data.SumFunction? But to use it you need to do that on the code-behind (or get the grid's instance on the viewmodel).

Comment: @Ivan I don't use it in code-behind. Not sure how to get the grid's instance on the ViewModel.

Comment: @Bigeyes, add new item via `Information` property which is the items source

Comment: @Nkosi but it wouldn't look like the sum and would be mixed with other data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

With this you can do it for specific columns via XAML (no need other code)

```
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Quantity"
                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding ProdQuantity}"
                            UniqueName="Quantity">
     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
         <telerik:SumFunction Caption="Sum: " />
     </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

---

OR For all numeric columns

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="myRadGridView" 
                     Width="1000" 
                     IsReadOnly="True" 
                     ...            

                     ShowColumnFooters="True" 
                     AutoGeneratingColumn="GridView_AutoGeneratingColumn"

                     ItemsSource="{Binding Information}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     SelectionChanged="myRadGridView_SelectionChanged"
                     >
```

In code:

```
    private void GridView_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!e.Column is GridViewDataColumn)
            return;
        GridViewDataColumn col = (e.Column as GridViewDataColumn);
        if (col.DataType != null)
        {
            if (col.DataType == typeof(Int32)  || col.DataType == typeof(long) || col.DataType == typeof(Double))           
                 e.Column.AggregateFunctions.Add(new SumFunction());            
        }   
    }
```

note that columns must be GridViewDataColumn

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I am not adding new column. My goal is to add a new row at the bottom if you would read my question again. ROW! NOT COLUMN.

Comment: @Bigeyes don't be mistaken by the function name, this actually adds a ROW at the bottom.

check here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/columns/aggregate-functions

Comment: So you still do it in code behind? I want to use it in my ViewModel. Otherwise I have to re-engineering the project. It is almost impossible.

Comment: I edited the answer to make ti more clear. There are two different ways, one only via xaml and one via code. You need to follow the xalm one.

Please check the link i provided before from telerik's documentation to learn more.

Comment: If I follow the xaml pattern, in your example. I only want to display the caption "Sum" on that column. In the on forwarding columns, then I will do the math. Is that ok?